# Relationship between a Banach Space $X$ and its bidual $X^{**}$

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation, weak-convergence, weak-topology, reflexive-space

Suppose $X$ is a Banach Space and $X^{**}$ is the bidual, $J:X\to X^{**}$ is the canonical map from $X$ to $X^{**}$. It's well known that $J$ might not be surjective.

My question is that: given $\phi \in X^{**}$, can we find a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset X$ such that $\{J(x_n)\}$ converges to $\phi$ in some sense (strongly or weakly)?

Answer (score 2):

It is not dense in the norm unless $X$ is reflexive but it is always dense in the weak* topology of $X^{**}$.

[If $X$ is not weak* dense in $X^{**}$ there would be an $x^{*} \in X^{*}$ other than $0$ which vanishes on $X$. But this is impossible. I am using Hahn Banach Theorem and  the fact that the dual of $(X^{**},weak*)$ is $X^{*}$].

As pointed out by KeeoerOfSecrets below sequences cannot be use for denseness in weak* topology.

Comment: I want to know the proof in the case of weak* topology.

Comment: @Kepler I have already included a proof. For the proof you will have to know what the dual of $(X^{**}},weak*)$ is.

Comment: It is also necessary to mention that in case of nonseparable Banach space $X$ sequences are not sufficient to describe the weak$^*$ closure.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets Thanks.  have added that to my answer.